# How to add a transition to all layers in VSDC video editor instead of having to it one by one?

Tags: video-editor

I'm using VSDC video editor. I have an image that last some seconds in each layer and I want to add to them a transformation effect to all of them at the end instead of having to do it one by one. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSDC team member is here. If you're talking about the transition effects, you can add them using the wizard. Although, you'll still have to drag each one for each transition.

However, if you need to copy any other effects, we have a how-to video for you: [How to apply the same effect to different objects with VSDC Free Video Editor.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gfm6-jv4aw&feature=youtu.be) 
I hope this helps!